# SQL query to filter many to many relationships

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have this tables for a many to many relationship

```
USER
-----
Id


CASE
----
Id
Created

Users_Cases
------------
UserId
CaseId
```

Can you help me figure out the sql query to get the users who's cases were created before a certain date (10/14/2015)? Thanks,

EDIT: If the user has 2 cases and the first case was created before the date and the other one after the date, the use should not be included in the result

```
User
User1
User2
User3

Case
Case1 - 9/14/2015
Case2 - 11/14/2015
Case3 - 12/14/2015
Case4 - 8/15/2015

Users_Cases
User1 - Case1
User1 - Case2
User2 - Case3
User3 - Case4
```

Expected result : Only User3. User1 has a case < than the date, but also has another case >= the date so user1 is not included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM "user" u
INNER JOIN "Users_Cases" uc ON u.id = uc.UserId
INNER JOIN "CASE" c ON uc.CaseId = c.id WHERE c.Created < '10/14/2015'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM "user"
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT UserId
        FROM "Users_Cases" uc
        INNER JOIN "CASE" c ON uc.CaseId = c.id WHERE c.Created < '10/14/2015' )
        )
```

---

EDIT : As per OP's comment

```
SELECT *
FROM "user"
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT uc.UserId
        FROM "case" c
        INNER JOIN "Users_Cases" uc ON uc.CaseId = c.id
        WHERE c.Created < '10/14/2015'
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but i forgot a condition, if supposedly the user has 2 cases and the first case was created before the date and the other one after the date, the use should not be included in the result. How would i modify the query above?

Comment: What does " _the use should not be included in the result_ " mean?? And I coudn't  understand you well, just show sample input and the expected out put it would be more sufficient to understand quickly

Comment: User
User1
User2
User3

Case
Case1 - 9/14/2015
Case2 - 11/14/2015
Case3 - 12/14/2015
Case4 - 8/15/2015

Users_Cases
User1 - Case1
User1 - Case2
User2 - Case3
User3 - Case4

Expected result : Only User3. User1 has a case < than the date, but also has another case >= the date so user1 is not included in the result.

Comment: Your query provides, the list of users raised cases before the specified date...  but I think OP wants to exclude users who have raised tickets after the specified date from the list...

Answer (score 1):

May be this should work, as I think you want to exclude those users who have created cases after a specified date.

```
Select * from User as A
    inner join UserCases as B on A.ID = B.UserID
    inner join case as C on B.CaseID = C.ID
Where C.Created <= @GivenDate
    and A.ID not in (Select UserID from User_cases as D 
                inner join case as E on D.CaseID = E.ID
                Where E.Created >= @GivenDate
            )
```

if you want only the one ID, use group by clause.

```
Select A.ID from User as A
    inner join UserCases as B on A.ID = B.UserID
    inner join case as C on B.CaseID = C.ID
Where C.Created <= @GivenDate
    and A.ID not in (Select UserID from User_cases as D 
                inner join case as E on D.CaseID = E.ID
                Where E.Created >= @GivenDate
            )
 group by A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.*
FROM `USER` AS U
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `Users_Cases` AS UC 
          INNER JOIN `case` AS C ON UC.CaseId=C.`id`
          WHERE UC.UserId=U.`id` 
          AND C.`Created`<'2015-10-14'
)
```